# Separate declaration and definition of specialization of template function : different behaviour for member and nonmember functions

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, template-specialization, function-templates

I want to declare specialization for function template, but define it later in source file. Consider next example:

`.hpp`

```
// approach #1
template <typename T> const char *GetTypeName();
template <> const char *GetTypeName<int>();

// approach #2
template <typename T> class TypeName {static const char *Get();};
template <> const char *TypeName<int>::Get();
```

`.cpp`

```
// approach #1
template <> const char *GetTypeName<int>()
{
    return "int"
}

// approach #2
template <> const char *TypeName<int>::Get()
{
    return "int"
}
```

In MSVC 2012 (CTP is **not** installed), both variants compile fine, but nonmember variant (**#1**) raises linker errors (unresolved externals, blah). Is it normal behaviour? MSVC specific? Compiler bug? Fixed in CTP?

**EDIT**
I am using specialized versions only. They are declared in headers and defined in sources. This approach works for members, but does not works for standalone functions.

**EDIT 2**
Hmm... I'm trying to build same snapshot at home (identical MSVC installation, no CTP), and it links without issues. Seems like local bug or corrupted installation.

Comment: Unresolved externals for the specializations, or what?  Are the uses in the same DLL, or a different DLL?

Comment: @JamesKanze Unresolved externals for nonmember specializations. I'm using only specialized versions. Standalone application, no DLLs.

Comment: And the source file with the implementation of the specializations is part of the project?

Comment: Could you edit your question to contain a complete example which doesn't work?  I've often done similar things (but perhaps not exactly the same), and it's always worked (both with MSVC and g++).

Comment: @JamesKanze Thank you for your efforts. Problem solved. See last update.

Answer (score 3):

A function template is not a function. A fully specialized function template *is* a function.

Since all (odr-used) functions must be defined, you must have a way to generate definitions for arbitrary template instantiations. Thus the definition of the primary function template must be in the header.

**header.h:**

```
template <typename T>            //  this
const char * GetTypeName()       //  is
{                                //  not
    return "foo";                //  a
}                                //  function

template <>
const char * GetTypeName<int>();
```

**impl.cpp:**

```
#include "header.h"

template <>
const char * GetTypeName<int>()
{
    return "int";
}
```

Comment: But I plan to use only specialized versions. I must provide definition for function template even in this case?

Comment: @ShadowsInRain No.  The compiler only needs a definition for the instantiations that it uses.  If you only use specialized versions, then those are the only definitions you need.

Comment: @JamesKanze And so it is. I am using specialized versions only, they are declared in headers and defined in sources.

Comment: I just tried something similar to this, with a call in `main` to `GetTypeName<double>` and it compiled, linked, an ran.
But if I move the *definition* of the template to the source file, I get the link error "undefined reference to `GetTypeName<double>`.
What would the correct way to define the template in the source file be?